# VBA for clear value in specific range of cell and protected cell from being wash away formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have data from like A1:Z50 but I want to delete only A5:X50 using VBA
(I think it will be a lot faster than dragging the whole cell or using `clickA5+shift+clickX50+delete`).
How can I do this ?

And then, how to lock the cell to prevent it from getting fixed or cleared ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Pls specify what you mean by "how do i prevent from clear the formula"

Comment: Yes i will add it up

at first i only want to delete but now i see the that my formula is gone too :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could define a macro containing the following code:

```
Sub DeleteA5X50()   
    Range("A5:X50").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
end sub
```

Running the macro would select the range A5:x50 on the active worksheet and clear all the contents of the cells within that range.

To leave your formulas intact use the following instead:

```
Sub DeleteA5X50()   
    Range("A5:X50").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
end sub
```

This will first select the overall range of cells you are interested in clearing the contents from and will then further limit the selection to only include cells which contain what excel considers to be 'Constants.'

You can do this manually in excel by selecting the range of cells, hitting 'f5' to bring up the 'Go To' dialog box and then clicking on the 'Special' button and choosing the 'Constants' option and clicking 'Ok'.

Comment: is it going to clear formula too right :D

how do i prevent from clear the formula :3 or no way

Comment: @Glenn you do not have to select to clear it :) `Sheets(1).Range("A5:X50").ClearContents` would do.

Comment: Benchmark: `Selection.ClearContents` (this answer) 11.625 seconds vs. `Selection.Value = ""` (Niklas's answer): 10.9375 seconds, or about a 5% speed difference.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
Sheets("your sheetname").range("A5:X50").Value = ""
```

You can also use

```
ActiveSheet.range
```

Comment: just change it to blank cell 
and on 
activesheet.range what does it mean :D

Comment: You can also use
    ActiveSheet.range("A5:X50").Value = ""

What do you want? Delete or empty it?

Comment: i understand it now :3 thank you 

is it gonna wash away cell color and backgrounds and Formula is cell

Comment: Maybe try this
range("A5:X50").Select
Selection.Delete

Comment: another question how do i lock formula in my cell prevent it from get delete

Comment: Hmm i don't know maybe there is a lock function / method.

Comment: @eathapeking setting a cell value to blank doesn't *wash away colours or any conditional formatting*.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure its faster with VBA - the fastest way to do it in the normal Excel programm would be:

1. `Ctrl-G`
2. `A1:X50 Enter`
3. `Delete`

Unless you have to do this very often, entering and then triggering the VBAcode is more effort.

And in case you only want to delete formulas or values, you can insert `Ctrl-G, Alt-S` to select Goto Special and here select Formulas or Values.